# How can I place two divs next to each other so that if one is not there then the other div will expand?

Tags: html, css

How can I place two div's next to each other such that if one is not there, the other will expand?

```
 <div class="main">
     <div class="left"></div>
     <div class="right"></div>
    </div>

.main{width:100%}
.left{width:70%}
.right{width:30%}
```

if left is not there right will be 100%;
if right is not there left will be 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```
.left{width:70%;}
.right{width:100%;}
.left+.right{width:30% !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below classes with your div's, you can set the width of right-div to 100% if left div is absent, or set the width of left-div to 100% if right is absent

```
<div class=main-div">
    <div class="left-div"></div>
    <div class="right-div"></div>
</div>

.main-div {width: 100%}
.left-div {float: left; 
    background: yellow; 
    width: 50%; 
    height: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;}
.right-div {float: right; 
    background: red; 
    width: 50%; 
    height: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;}
```